# How can I edit an embed field with a button in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, discord-buttons

Basically, I'm making a poll command. I want it to put the user's vote in the embed field, and obviously make it so they can't vote again, again, and again. No idea how to do this.

[Command Preview Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/502Fe.png)

Here's the code:

```
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, emoji='')
    async def upvote_button(self, button : discord.ui.Button, interaction : discord.Interaction):
        pass

    @discord.ui.button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji='')
    async def downvote_button(self, button : discord.ui.Button, interaction : discord.Interaction):
        pass

class Poll(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="poll", description="Ask a question and receive upvotes or downvotes (Yes/No)")
    async def poll(self, interaction : discord.Interaction, *, question : str):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=question,
            color = 0xb037e1
        )
        embed.set_author(name="Poll", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text="Asked by: " + str(interaction.user), icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)

        embed.add_field(name="Upvotes", value="X", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Downvotes", value="X", inline=True)

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=Buttons())
```

Probably very simple, although I still haven't thought about a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using `dictionaries`, `lists`, or even `sets` to store the users that have clicked.

For this example, I will use one list to store the users who have clicked the upvote and downvote buttons. Like here:

```py
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout or 180)

        self.voted_users = []

        self.upvote_count = 0
        self.downvote_count = 0

    @discord.ui.button(
        label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, emoji=""
    )
    async def upvote_button(
        self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button
    ):
        if (
            interaction.user in self.voted_users
        ):  # check if the user has already voted or not and return if true
            return await interaction.response.send_message(
                content="You've already voted!", ephemeral=True
            )

        self.upvote_count += 1
        self.voted_users.append(interaction.user)  # add the user to voted list

        await interaction.response.send_message("Upvoted!", ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji="")
    async def downvote_button(
        self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button
    ):
        if (
            interaction.user in self.voted_users
        ):  # check if the user has already voted or not and return if true
            return await interaction.response.send_message(
                content="You've already voted!", ephemeral=True
            )

        self.downvote_count += 1
        self.voted_users.append(interaction.user)  # add the user to voted list

        await interaction.response.send_message("Downvoted!", ephemeral=True)
```

By the way, `interaction` always comes before the `button` in the button callback argument if you're using `discord.py`.